# Reduce spacing between authors in article title

Tags: spacing, titles

I am creating the frontpage of an article I am working with using the `\maketitle`command. So far this is what I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{\textbf{Some title}}
\author{John Doe \\ University of Arizona \\ and
    \and John Doe \\ University of Arizona  \\ and
    \and John Doe \\ University of Arizona}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

And this is the result obtained:
[image]

However, Latex leaves blank a lot of space between the author and the university, and also between authors. I would like to reduce that space, but I dont known how to change it.

Comment: Why are you even using the word `and` between them? Note really necessary when you separate vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding some negative space:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{\textbf{Some title}}
\author{John Doe \\\vspace{-1em} University of Arizona \\
    \and John Doe \\\vspace{-1em} University of Arizona  \\
    \and John Doe \\\vspace{-1em} University of Arizona}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use `authblk`, which has a setting for this (`\affilsep`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{A Multiauthor Work}
\author{John Doe\\University of Life\and
  Richard Roe\\School of Hard Knocks\and
  Zoe Zoe\\Insitution of Institutional Thought}
\setlength{\affilsep}{2pt}%<- this affects spacing
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\itshape}%<-or whatever
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: title page]